# Solr SEARCH BY entity name

Tags: solr, dataimporthandler

```
<dataConfig>
        <dataSource type="JdbcDataSource" driver="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver">        
        <document>
                <entity name="MALE_PROFILES"
                query="SELECT ID , COLUMN1 , COLUMN2,male FROM MALE_PROFILES "
                 transformer="RegexTransformer">
                        <field name="id" column="ID">
                </entity>
                <entity name="FEMALE_PROFILES"
                query="SELECT ID , COLUMN1 , COLUMN2,female FROM FEMALE_PROFILES"
                 transformer="RegexTransformer">
                        <field name="id" column="ID">
                </entity>
        </document>
</dataConfig>
```

Currently my search is based on male and female, which should be slow.
Can I search based on entity name like MALE_PROFILE ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Its not going to be slow unless you have lots and lots of records with a huge index size.
For search based on entities, you can add a identifier to the male and female profiles and use [filter queries](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/CommonQueryParameters#fq) to limit the searched entities which will use the [filter cache](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/CommonQueryParameters#Caching_of_filters) as well.
e.g.

if you add a fixed column with your male and female entities,

SELECT ID , COLUMN1 , COLUMN2,male, `'MALE' AS PROFILE` FROM MALE_PROFILES

you can apply the filter using fq=profile:MALE

Comment: but i guess in this case it need to search in way larger records.
i have 6 such indexes each having 10 lacs records

so if i guess its better to search in 10 lac record then in 60 lacs record

Comment: One core for 60 lacs records would still work fine. Whats ur index size ? We have over million records in a single core and the response is within ms but it depends on type of data and configurations as well.